# Extracting extra column describing what people are known for from dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to select all influences of a person but also know what they are known for. I can select `/Person` or `/Writer` or `/Scientist` but can I output another column which is an attribute giving their field somehow?

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
    ?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> . 
    ?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced . 
    ?influenced a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
}
```

Also, how do I just select all the names of just a particular ontology? Say I just want a list of all /Painters inside dbpedia? I am using [sparql](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Getting all the painters

If you want a list of all Painters, you'll have to determine how to define a painter based on data in DBpedia.  E.g., if you look at http://dbpedia.org/page/Pablo_Picasso, you'll see some useful properties, e.g.,

- rdf:type yago:Painter110391653
- rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Artist
- rdf:type http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Artist

Your query would have to be based on this kind of data.  E.g., you could ask for

```
select ?painter { ?painter a dbpedia-owl:Artist , yago:Painter110391653 }
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?painter%20%7B%20?painter%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aArtist%20,%20yago%3aPainter110391653%20%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

### Getting a "field" people are known for

This is too broad, because people can be known for lots of things.  You'll probably need to look through some DBpedia entries and see what sorts of information is available.  If you're looking for the profession or vocation that someone is known for, you'll need to look for property values that give some indication of that, and figure out which ones you want to use.  One that might be useful is dbpprop:field.  http://dbpedia.org/page/Vincent_van_Gogh has the value

- dbpprop:field "Painting, drawing"

To retrieve some of those values, you might use a query like

```
select ?painter ?field { 
  ?painter a dbpedia-owl:Artist , yago:Painter110391653 .
  optional { 
    ?painter dbpprop:field ?field
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?painter%20?field%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20?painter%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aArtist%20,%20yago%3aPainter110391653%20.%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?painter%20dbpprop%3afield%20?field%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

In general though, you'll need to explore the data and figure out what you want to extract.  Only then can you really ask for effective ways to extract it.